# AWS S3 proxy saves raw form-data instead of the actual file. Why?

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipartform-data, form-data

Good morning to everyone.

I am trying to directly upload a binary file (either a picture or an audio file) to a S3 bucket from a web browser by using AWS API Gateways, but avoiding lambda functions and signed urls following the guide on

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

Since multipart/form-data seems the only choice in this case, I am using jQuery and Ajax to upload the file with FormData. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('Content-Type', file.type);
fd.append("success_action_status", null);
fd.append("file",<file>);

$.ajax({
    url: ***,
    data: fd,
    type: "PUT",
    processData: false,     
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": ***,
        "x-amz-meta-filename" : file.name,
        "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data"
    }
})
    .done(function(data ) {
        callback(null,data);
    })
    // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
    // status codes are passed to the function
    .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {            
        callback({status: xhr.status, message: xhr.responseText}, null);
    });
```

I was able to create the API in the gateway and I also set to passthrough "multipart/form-data" to S3 to prevent converting form-data from binary to text.

Unfortunately, although the file upload succeeds, S3 stores the raw form data instead of the actual file, making it unreadable when retrieved in a second time.

Here's a snippet of the "binary" file created in S3 and opened with a text editor. The original file is a picture...

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryHZlvlkeiOZpIVeJC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

image/jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryHZlvlkeiOZpIVeJC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"

null
------WebKitFormBoundaryHZlvlkeiOZpIVeJC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="index.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿà JFIF      ÿÛ „    ( %!1!%)+...383-7(-.+
```

I have no idea about this behavior, nor how to make S3 store the file and not the raw payload.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Example 1 in the [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html?shortFooter=true)? What made you think S3 will be able to process a multipart/form-data request? It seems when you want to store a file, you must not send any other data in the request than the file contents itself. Use Content-Encoding header, don't use multiple Content-Types. Keep reading the manual until you understand the requirements.

Comment: Can you please point me out how to change my JS Ajax code to make this, work? According to the link I posted and the fact that the API Gateway now [should] supports multipart/form-data I thought/hoped what I did was correct, but it is clear it wasn't. Thanks.

Comment: Forget form, don't send FormData. Especaill `fd.append('Content-Type', file.type);` makes no sense. Content-Type is a header but here you basically say that your form has an input whose name is Content-Type. That input field does not relate to the file in the form. You must send the file contents only in the body of the request.

Comment: I tried putting the file directly in "data" of the $ajax and moved the file content type in the header section. It seems to work, now the file has the correct size and can be retrieved correctly. I will try with larger files to see everything keeps working as expected. Thanks for the help, you saved my day. I wonder why there is not an example in AWS docs clearly explaining this issue and how to properly handle file upload to S3 from browsers with API gateway.